# Is there a way of defining the size of the key value?

Tags: c#, hashtable

In C# is there a way of defining the key size when you instantiate a new hash table?

```
Hashtable myHash = new Hashtable();
```

I want to use a long value for the key size but I seem to be exceeding the available key size as I am getting negative numbers.  I am multiplying together some prime numbers, the largest returned value being 23*23*23*23*23*23*23*23*23 = 1801152661463.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should use `HashSet<T>` if you're using .net 3.5 or newer, and `Dictionary<T,bool>` if you're using .net 2. Generic collections offer better compiletime checks, less casts and less boxing.

The int overflow most likely happens before insertion into the `Hashtable` in your current code. So you're observed bug is most likely unrelated to `Hashtable`, but it's a bug in your arithmetic code. You probably need to cast something to `long`. But unless you post the relevant code, I can't tell you where exactly the overflow happens.

Comment: You are probably right, I will go back and check, probably in the multiplication section.

Comment: thanks, you were correct, I was multiplying the values as ints and the max value was being exceeded, and then written to a long.  I converted them all to long before the multiplication line and it now works correctly.  I validated the results and they are indeed correct.  Thank you your comment really did help.

Answer (score 0):

Both the .NET `Hashtable` and `HashSet<T>` classes call `object.GetHashCode()` to retrieve the hash.  Since `GetHashCode()` returns an `int`, that is the size of the hash key that is used.

If you'd like to provide your own hash function, you can either override `GetHashCode()` in the type you'll be inserting, or define a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` and pass it to the HashSet constructor.  However, the `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode()` method also returns an integer key, so I'm not sure this will meet your needs.

If your application needs a hash key larger than an `int`, you may need to create your own HashSet data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `System.Object` method [`GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) returns an int, I would say that your choice of hash code algorithm is restricted to those returning a 32-bit value (whether you want to call it signed or unsigned doesn't make a differece: the hash value is just an arbitrary 32-bit value).

And HashTable doesn't care what your keys or values are: as far is it's concerned, they're both just objects. You might want to make sure that your're properly overriding and implementing [`GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) and [`Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx). Might want to think about your implementation of `IComparable` as well.